# how to remove this.$set when migration from vue2 to vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, migration, vuejs3

I am doing migration from vue2 to vue3 and I need to remove $set as required.

So for example, in my application my code is like this in vue2:

```
this.$set(..., ..., null);
```

So to delete it should I use additional package like tiny-emitter and apply it like this?

```
emitter.set(..., ..., null);
```

How can I remove $set from my application for vue3?

Comment: Use a regular array method, rather than `set`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need vue Set anymore because reactivity is now work fine in Vue3.

So to replace this.$set for an array you can juste do that:

```js
// Old vue2 -> this.$set(array, index, null);
this.array[index] = null
```

So in each use you have, you just need to do the basic JS you need, and do not care about reactivity issue :).